# Is it possible to sort an array using one temporary variable/space?

Tags: arrays, sorting, adhoc

Suppose an array is given by a1, a2, ..., ak, _ , a(k+1), ..., an.
Here an underscore (_) represents blank space. We can move any array element to this space. We can repeat this operation any number of times. Is it possible to sort every array with one such blank space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

A sorted array is just a particular permutation of that array.

Any permutation can be arrived at by a sequence of individual swaps.

And a swap can be implemented with a single temporary element.

(It's actually possible to sort an array of integral types *without* a temporary, using XOR operations).

Comment: Thank you. I even don't know that the without-temporary-swap have a version using XOR.      
 a = a ^ b;
 b = a ^ b;
 a = a ^ b;
or via plus/minus :
 a = a + b;
 b = a - b;
 a = a - b;

Answer (score 0):

There are several algorithms for in-place sorting. The most notable one is the non-recursive version of quick-sort (as the recursive version would occupy space on the stack proportional to the number of recursive calls), that on average will grant you O(n log n) complexity.

Another possibility is to use less efficient algorithms, such as insertion sort and bubble sort, whose complessity is O(n^2).

For what regards your specific question, that is to use that specific space, you can use it for swapping as said by Bathsheba, but i wouldn't lost my time doing this kind of operation.

Consider also the fact that if you have explicit notion of a "unused space" in the middle of your array, you should try to understand its semantic, that is, what would be its correct placement in terms of ordering. If you don't, and you leave it where it is, you would find yourself with a "broken" invariant and you will have difficulties in implementing algorithms like binary search on your collection.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such containers yet in actual code, but the easiest algorithm to implement (not the most efficient!) is to swap empty with first element, then swap smallest with empty on first place, then assume that the container starts at second position and repeat until the last position, which will be the empty space. In this case, swap just means, fill in empty space and mark other position as empty.